# contextswitchdeadlock 

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, contextswitchdeadlock

Whilst debugging my program in VS 2008 I have come across the following error:

The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x34fc1a0 to COM context 0x34fc258 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this

It appears to be deadlocking even though the code only contains a simple C# timer: See Snippet Below:

```
    private void RequestWork()
    {
        // The timer will be re-intialised if there are still no wating jobs in the database
        StopTimer();

        // assign all the threads some work
        InitialiseTimer();

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise a timer with a timer interval configured from app.config. Enable the timer and 
    /// register an appropriate event handler
    /// </summary>
    private void InitialiseTimer()
    {


        if (m_Timer == null)
        {
            // look up the default backoff time from the config
            string backOffInt = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BackOffInterval"];

            int backoffInterval = 1000;


            m_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();


            // set the timer interval to 5 seconds
            m_Timer.Interval = backoffInterval;

            m_Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(m_Timer_Elapsed);
        }

        m_Timer.Enabled = true;
    }


    private void StopTimer()
    {

        if (m_Timer != null)
        {
            m_Timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void m_Timer_Elapsed(object p_Sender, ElapsedEventArgs p_E)
    {

        RequestWork();
    }
```

As far as I know the timer should run, elapse and then initialise again, I can see no local reason for a deadlock.

I am aware of how to turn this error msg off but feel that this is not a solution, instead it is masking the problem.

Comment: Does this bit of code reproduces the error?

Answer (score 5):

You can turn this off if you think you've definitely *not* got a deadlock situation:

Debug->Exceptions->Managed Debug Assistants menu in Visual Studio and uncheck the ContextSwitchDeadlock

Answer (score 5):

This is an infinite loop. You need to let your application pump some messages at least once every 60 seconds to prevent this exception to happen.
Try calling System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(10) once in a while. There are other calls you can do that let the messages pump.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are adding a new event handler each time you call InitialiseTimer. That way m_Timer_Elapsed will be called as many times as it has been added. 
You should add the event handler just one time.

Comment: only  if (m_Timer == null), should only get set once or until something unset's it.

Answer (score 1):

If your application hangs or not reponse even after you uncheck the box against contextswitchdeadlock. Put the following line before call of method or for loop.

In C#

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

and VB.NET / VB / ASP.NET

```
DoEvents()
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts/questions:

1)  The code snippet looks like your interval is every 1 second (not 5 as mentioned in the comments).
2)  The big question is what is `RequestWork()` doing?

Without knowing what `RequestWork()` is doing, we can't really comment on why you are seeing a ContextSwitchDeadlock.

Somethings to think about with respect to this method
a) how long does it take?
b) is it accessing GUI elements?

Some MSDN comments on Elapsed:

> If you use the Timer with a user
>   interface element, such as a form or
>   control, assign the form or control
>   that contains the Timer to the
>   SynchronizingObject property, so that
>   the event is marshaled to the user
>   interface thread.

-and-

> The Elapsed event is raised on a
>   ThreadPool thread. If processing of
>   the Elapsed event lasts longer than
>   Interval, the event might be raised
>   again on another ThreadPool thread.
>   Thus, the event handler should be
>   reentrant.

I'm thinking since you have a 1 second timer, you might want to look into what happens in RequestWork and see how long its taking.