# Handling ContextSwitchDeadlock when no user interaction is expected?

Tags: multithreading, com

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797677/contextswitchdeadlock-was-detected-error-in-c-sharp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106159/net-contextswitchdeadlock-was-detected) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334360/contextswitchdeadlock) this but my situation carries a caveat, no UI. There's 2 main solutions, neither of which I like. One repeated answer says to offload the work on a background thread. My app is started with command line parameters by another program and generates a report to a specific folder. I believe there's no reason it should have an unoccupied main thread to respond to input that it's not expected to receive and going to do anything with. The window's not even visible for a user to interact with. The other solution is to turn off the warning so it goes unnoticed. This sounds too much like ignoring a fire.

Can I change the thread's ApartmentState, Culture, or Principal to avoid this error? I must admit I don't know much about any of those things.

Comment: Why do you create a window if the user is never going to interact with it?  The warning basically implies that the window isn't going to work.  So there's just no point in creating one.

Comment: There is no window. It's a console application whose console does not appear.

Comment: Ok, it's technically a Windows Form Application, but it does not actually create a window. Like this question and it's marked answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/how-can-i-hide-a-console-window

Comment: Remove the [STAThread] attribute from the Main() method.

Comment: @Hans Passant, There isn't one.

Comment: Also, for the record, this is a VB.Net app.

Comment: I'm just going to wait a day or two until you're done dribbling important details like that.

Comment: I didn't think that the language was critical. In my understanding, this exact same app in C# or F# would have the exact same problems. No previous answer has been language specific.